# Is there any way to change the doughnut chart color in ng2-charts?

Tags: css, canvas, colors, customization, ng2-charts

I try to change doughnut chart colors.

Here is my current chart:

[image]

Now, I try to change these colors as follows `#fa72bc`,`#00bfff` and `#ffa500`.

I changed the colors for "line chart" and "bar chart" using the following code:

**BAR CHART:**

```
public barChartColors:Array<any> =
[
  { // Pink
    backgroundColor: '#fa72bc'
  },
  { // Blue
    backgroundColor: '#00bfff'
  },
  { // Orange
    backgroundColor: '#ffa500'
  },
  { // Green
    backgroundColor: '#3ec351'
  }
];
```

*Customized Chart:*

[image]

**LINE CHART:**

```
public lineChartColors:Array<any> = 
[
  { // grey
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
    pointBorderColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
  },
  { // dark grey
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)',
    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)',
    pointBorderColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)'
  },
  { // grey
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
    pointBorderColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
  }
];
```

I Tried the Same bar chart code for Doughnut Chart.But, This is what I got.

[image]

I want to customize the chart with different colors. But, the chart displays only one color. I don't know how to solve this. Can you help me.

Thanks in Advance... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this example,

```
   <canvas baseChart
          [data]="doughnutChartData"
          [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
          [backgroundColor]="doughnutColors"
          [chartType]="doughnutChartType"
          (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
          (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>


    private donutColors=[
    {
     backgroundColor: [
    'rgba(110, 114, 20, 1)',
     'rgba(118, 183, 172, 1)',
     'rgba(0, 148, 97, 1)',
     'rgba(129, 78, 40, 1)',
     'rgba(129, 199, 111, 1)'
     ]
     }
     ];
```

Comment: Wow, Thanks. It's Working Fine for Me.  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    private GREEN = [{
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgb(39,141,98)',
            'rgb(98,183,159)',
            'rgb(39,141,98,0.05)',
        ],
    }];

    private BLUE = [{
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgb(27,110,161)',
            'rgb(84,168,197)',
            'rgb(27,110,161,0.05)',
        ],
    }];

    private YELLOW =  [{
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgb(197,133,47)',
            'rgb(201,172,80)',
            'rgba(197,133,47,0.05)',
        ],
    }];

private doughnutColorsList = new Map<String, any>([["GREEN",this.GREEN]
        ,["BLUE",this.BLUE],
        ["YELLOW",this.YELLOW]);

<canvas
                                baseChart
                                [data]="data"
                                [options]="doughnutChartOptions"
                                [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
                                [chartType]="doughnutChartType"
                                [colors]="doughnutColorsList.get(color.key)"
                        >
```

> To get the color depending on a color key - different colors

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is no longer valid for version 3 of ng2-charts. Now instead of using the [backgroundColor] parameter, you have to use [data] and include a backgroundColor array inside of the dataSet. Like this:

HTML

```
<canvas baseChart
        [data]="doughnutChartData"
        [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
        [type]="doughnutChartType">
</canvas>
```

TS

```
import { ChartData, ChartType } from 'chart.js';

...
  public doughnutChartType: ChartType = 'doughnut'
  public doughnutChartLabels: string[] = ['Paused', 'Completed', 'Expired'];
  public doughnutChartData: ChartData<'doughnut'> = {
    labels: this.doughnutChartLabels,
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [3, 8, 1],
        
        backgroundColor: ["red", "green", "blue"],
        hoverBackgroundColor: ["darkred", "darkgreen", "darkblue"],
        hoverBorderColor: ["grey"]
      }
    ]
  };
```

You can read the documentation for the current version here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html